# How do we show all logs in Spring Actuator?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logging, spring-boot-actuator

I setup Spring Actuator for checking health and log, But in /logfile that shown only  current day log but didn't show past log.

Following is **application.properties**

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoint.logfile.external-file=/var/tmp/AuthService.log
```

So anyone can help me out that how can i show all logs in Spring Actuator?

Comment: Looks like the logs are rolling. Check if you have a daily rolling file appender configured and if so, previous days's logs will be in a file with the date appended to them.

Comment: Thanks for replay, but we didn't use rolling file appender. is there any default setting for rolling file appender ?